# import cannot be resolved for ConnectivityManager Class

Tags: android, voip

How can I fix this error?

> import cannot be resolved

[image]

I have jars for annotation in this path android Sdk:

> D:\outils\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\26.0.0-alpha1

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting see the class `ConnectivityManager.java` and your imports really can't be resolved because him are compiled by Android Library

Comment: thanks Abner, but how can i resolve this problem. I'll want to use this class in my project. Can you please explain your answer.